# Change Sql "Not In" To "Left Outer Join"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I don't want to use "not in" this sql query. How can I do it? thanks

```
SELECT  
 T2.Sno,
 T2.Name,
 T1.description,
 T2.UserCode            
FROM 
 Table1 AS T1 (nolock)
    INNER JOIN T2 (nolock)
    ON T1.UserCode = T2.UserCode
WHERE
 g.xid= @p_xid
 and T2.Sno not in (select Gid from T3 (nolock))
```

Comment: Although `NOT IN` is usually a red flag design-wise, changing it to a `LEFT JOIN`-`IS NULL/NOT EXISTS` is actually worse most of the time.  Make sure you check your execution plan and make sure that this is really what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple T3 rows per `T2.Sno = T3.Gid`, you'll need DISTINCT in a JOIN.

- Without DISTINCT, it's a different query
- With DISTINCT, it's an extra step.

I'd use NOT EXISTS which avoids this.

```
SELECT  
 T2.Sno,
 T2.Name,
 T1.description,
 T2.UserCode            

FROM 
 Table1 AS T1 (nolock)
    INNER JOIN T2 (nolock)
    ON T1.UserCode = T2.UserCode
WHERE
 g.xid= @p_xid
 and not exists (select * from T3 (nolock) where T3.Gid = T2.Sno)
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming there is no row in T2 where Sno is null and in T3 where Gid is null:

```
SELECT  
 T2.Sno,
 T2.Name,
 T1.description,
 T2.UserCode            
FROM 
 Table1 AS T1 WITH (nolock)
    INNER JOIN T2 WITH (nolock)
      LEFT JOIN T3 WITH (NOLOCK)
      ON T2.Sno = T3.Gid
    ON T1.UserCode = T2.UserCode
WHERE
 g.xid= @p_xid
 and T3.Gid IS NULL
```